# Reading Soundcloud methods in the widget api

Tags: javascript, widget, soundcloud

I am keen to access control the Soundcloud Widget data.

I just can't recall the syntax to set api_setVolume() to zero ie mute.

This is the code I've put in the  tag

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/soundcloud.player.api.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
soundcloud.debug = true;
var api_setVolume = 0;
soundcloud.addEventListener('onPlayerReady', function(player, data) {
   player.api_play();
});
soundcloud.addEventListener('onMediaStart', function(player, data) {
    player.api_setVolume();
});
</script>
</head>`
```

Advice much appreciated,

Dazzer

Answer (score 0):

`player.api_setVolume();` should be `player.api_setVolume(0);`